# Google Visualization not appearing in heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, google-visualization

I have implemented the [google_visualr](https://github.com/winston/google_visualr) gem and it works perfectly in development. However when I push to heroku the visualization does not show up. All the javascript is present and there is no error or indication in the app logs.

Here is the javascript that is generated. It's exactly the same as dev. Do i have to do anything additional to get the google visualization to run in heroku environment?

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: function() {
    var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();data_table.addColumn('string', 'Status');data_table.addColumn('number', 'Count');data_table.addRow([{v: 'Started Applications'}, {v: 10}]);data_table.addRow([{v: 'Completed Applications'}, {v: 1}]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_chart'));
    chart.draw(data_table, {width: 360, height: 240, title: 'Applications Status Summary', is3D: true, legend: 'bottom'});
  }});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem was that my call to the google jsapi was not secure so the browser was blocking the request.

```
<script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
```

I was able to fix this by requesting the jsapi in secure mode using https

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing additional to be done to get the visualizations to work on Heroku.

The demo site is hosted on Heroku too: http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/examples/interactive/pie_chart

Just to check, is this in the *head* tag, at the top of the page?

```
<script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
```

Comment: yes the tag is included in the <head> section. Its quite strange. I'm going to open a heroku ticket and will let you know if they can figure it out.